# Sending values from Jframe to Jframe in Ecplise

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans

So, I'm stuck with a problem. I'm doing a project where I have to write queries in `SQL`, and so far, I've done it, but the problem is that I'm supposed to have a button that opens a new `JFrame`. This `JFrame` would be opened with a text field where you would write the query, then press `OK`, and the data would be sent to the mainframe and executed.

I'm using `Ecplise`.  The guides I found to do it with `Netbeans` haven't worked.

So far i have made the first frame work. This is what I have:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  try {
    Query q = new Query(null);
    q.setVisible(true);//This opens the supposed second frame
    String query = query.getText();  // I'm doing the query on the main frame, this data should be acquired from the query frame
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

On the query frame, I have a textfield and an OK button.  When the OK button is pressed, the data should be assigned to the "String query".  Any help on how to do it?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). *"..a text field where you would write the query, then press OK"* Use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..);`. It's built for such tasks.

Comment: i know but i have to do it this way, is too hard to send data from a jframe to an other?

Comment: I'm not expending effort to implement a poor requirement.